# Include multiple Multipage Dash Apps into Flask - url problems

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

Goal: A Flask App that has multiple Multipage Apps embedded. The dash pages sometimes can have similar names, so possible URLs would be "/app1/page1" and "app2/page1". Using pure flask code instead of dash is not really an option at the moment.

Implementation so far:

- initialise Flask App
- initialise Dash Apps via function (with the flask server provided and different url_base_pathnames)

Problem:
Dash pages are registered not per dash app but across all dash apps (url_base_pathname is ignored when registering the page)
--> pages can't have the same names (dash error "duplicate pathnames" for the same page name is thrown)

Any insights or advice is appreciated!

here is some minimal example code:

```
from flask import Flask
from dash import Dash, html
import dash

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<a href='/app1/pageapp1'>Dash App 1</a><hr><a href='/app2/pageapp2'>Dash App 2</a>"


def init_dash_app1(server):
    # configure app
    dash_app = Dash(
        server=server,
        url_base_pathname="/app1/",
        use_pages=True,
        pages_folder="",
    )
    dash.register_page(
        "page1app1",
        path="/page1",
        layout=html.Div("This is test page 1 from App 1"),
    )
    return dash_app.server


def init_dash_app2(server):
    # configure app
    dash_app = Dash(
        server=server,
        url_base_pathname="/app2/",
        use_pages=True,
        pages_folder="",
    )
    dash.register_page(
        "page1app2",
        path="/page1",
        layout=html.Div("This is test page 1 from App 2"),
    )
    return dash_app.server


app = init_dash_app1(app)
app = init_dash_app2(app)
```

btw in the page_registry the paths are registered as "/page1" and "/page2". I guess this is the problem. I want the url_base_pathname to be part of the page-url! The relative_path argument looks like it's what I want, but I'm not sure how (and if) this is used.

```
OrderedDict([('page1app1',
              {'module': 'page1app1',
               'supplied_path': '/page1',
               'path_template': None,
               'path': '/page1',
               'supplied_name': None,
               'name': 'Page1app1',
               ...
               'relative_path': '/app2/page1'}),
             ('page1app2',
              {'module': 'page1app2',
               'supplied_path': '/page1',
               'path_template': None,
               'path': '/page1',
               'supplied_name': None,
               'name': 'Page1app2',
               ...
               'relative_path': '/app2/page1'})])
```